# Rails, order parents w/ pagination by child created_at, unless child.nil, order by parent created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `video#index` I'm trying to order `video` objects by the most recent `created_at` time of their optionally present child element, `comment`, otherwise order by parent `video` element `created_at`.

I'm refactoring from this...

```
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @videos = Video.tagged_with(params[:tag]).page(params[:page]).per_page(10).order(created_at: "desc")
    else
      @videos = Video.all.page(params[:page]).per_page(10).order(created_at: "desc")
    end
  end
```

but unsure of how to structure the desired function.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is in refactoring here is to create scopes in your model to DRY it out:

```
class Video
  scope :newest, ->{ order(created_at: :desc) }

  def self.paginate(page = 1, per_page: 10)
    self.page(page).per_page(10)
  end 
end
```

You can compose scopes in rails by mutating variables:

```
@videos = Video.all
if params[:tag]
  @videos = @videos.tagged_with(params[:tag]) 
end
```

Or by using `.merge` and `.merge!`:

```
@videos = Video.paginate(params[:page]).tap.do |s|
  if params[:tag]
    s.merge!(Video.tagged_with(params[:tag]))
  else
    s.merge!(Video.newest))
  end
end
```